# Remove files from git without interfering with remote

Tags: git

I'm working on an open source project and I've forked their repository to my Github. Unfortunately, their github contains a number of resources that I'm not going to use - namely large asset files that bulk up the repositories size by about a hundred megabytes. Even worse, I've committed to my repository and pushed to it as well, so the history of my repository has these files versioned - which means if those files change in the main repository, then my commits will conflict with theirs and they will be unable to automatically merge.

Is there a way that I can exclude certain files that I have already committed/pushed to from my repository **without** affecting the fork repository when I push to it? Ideally I want to make git think that those files were never in my repository.

Comment: What is the problem with the "big" files? Is it just the disk space requirements of your clone? Or is pulling/pushing taking too long?

Comment: Pulling/pushing takes a very long time, yeah. 100MB of files that I'm not using (which is set to increase by quite a large amount)

Comment: Actually, pulling/pushing should only be affected if there are changes to the large files (on your side, or on the remote). Otherwise git will see that both sides have the current version and will not transfer them again. So if you want to get faster pushes/pulles you should probably start by figuring out why they are slow.

Comment: And BTW, please edit your question to indicate the project (and link to it), if it is public.

Comment: And finally: The sentence "Even worse, I've committed to my repository and pushed to it as well, so the history of my repository has these files versioned" does not make sense. If you clone a repo, you get its complete history for all files - it does not matter if you have committed to the clone or not. Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Sure thing. I've fixed the issue now, but: the git database in objects was nearing 300MB due to the assets being lumped in with all of the code, and git push was attempting to push that database up meaning 300MB pushes = not good. As for your last point, I had a fork, so I affected my own history and the commits I had made still had the 300MB assets in. Of course i also had the original history as well, but I wasn't working from a blank repository, I had already committed code that "knew" the Assets so-to-speak, so I needed to modify the history. Finally, I can't link to the project anymore as

Comment: Issue has been fixed. You can see my fix at github.com/PokemonNXT though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git filter-branch` to obliterate files from the entire history of the project. This will however rewrite every commit in the entire history and for all practical purposes, your fork will become a completely separate project with different commits that "incidentally" shares files with the source repository.

Once you do this, you can do a force push to your fork and the original files won't be there anymore even in the history. This will make git thing that "those files were never in my repository" but I'm not sure if that's a good thing or if you're considering all the consequences

*Update:*

Here's how you do it.

- First make a backup of your repository
- Assuming the point from where you want to rewrite the history is `master`, run this `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f <list of assets to delete>'`.
- This will rewrite the entire tree. Do a `git log` to double check.
- Once you're happy, `git push --force` this to your fork. You can even delete your fork and push to a fresh repository since it will be all different anyway.

The other branches will still have references and links to the old commits so if you want to delete the actual blobs from the repository, you have to delete all the references(tags, branches etc.) that are not rewritten and then run `git gc` on the repository.

Comment: I'm aware of the consequences of my actions, however I cannot let my section of the project (which is just pure code) 'depend' on the state of the assets

Comment: I think a better way of asking this question is: If I delete the assets in my local repository and push the changes, will this commit then be executed on the original ,non-forked repository if I try and merge them (i.e, I submit a pull request to Github, will github then delete the files that I deleted in the commit on my branch or will it ask for a merge resolution?)

Comment: I've posted details on how to do this.

Comment: I don't mind not re-writing history, if it means that making a commit deleting all of the assets will not affect the main repository (or git will ask for merge resolution)

Comment: IF you just `git rm` and `git commit`, the files will not be present from that point in time. This "deletion commit" can be merged back to the main repository but if the assets have changed since the time of forking, you'll get a merge conflict.

Comment: That's fine, that just means that the owner of the repo can resolve that conflict by ignoring the duplications, and then my repository won't track the assets - in theory anyway

Comment: It would make more sense for you to have an `asset-free` branch that doesn't have the assets or maybe the assets outside the main repository in a submodule.

Comment: I agree with that, but right now that's out of my control as I'm not the owner of the main repository.